# Why can't I order by after doing a concat with a % sign

Tags: sql

```
Select category, 
       concat(count(category) * 100/ (select count(*) from table3),'%') as category_percentage_males 
from   table3 
where  gender in ('m') 
group by category 
order by category_percentage_males desc
```

For some reason the order by doesn't return desc once I concat. Without the concat the order by works fine. Any reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please show sample data to illustrate what you're seeing?  I assume it's because you're expecting a numerical sort, but they're strings, so they follow string sorting.

Comment: Got it! However, when I simply don't include concat and leave it as follows: count(category) * 100/  select count(*) from table3) as category_percentage I am able to order by desc in order to get the top 3 categories by percentage @Siyual

Comment: Right - because that's a numerical value.  `CONCAT()` returns a string value.  Strings and numbers sort differently.

Comment: Makes sense. How can I add the % sign to the numerical percentage without making it into a string? Is that possible? @Siyual

Comment: Try adding the numerical portion, without the `CONCAT()` and `%` to the `ORDER BY`, in the place of the column name.

Comment: @Siyual That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
Select category, concat(count(category) * 100/ (select count(*) from table3),'%') as category_percentage_males
from table3 where gender in ('m')
group by category
order by category_percentage_males desc;
```

I would strongly suggest that you require it as:

```
Select category,
       concat(avg(case when gender = 'm' then 100.0 else 0 end), '%') as category_percentage_males
group by category
order by avg(case when gender = 'm' then 100.0 else 0 end) desc;
```